# Try to get the anchor tag

Tags: .net, vb.net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am trying to get anchor tag but i am getting run time error here is my code

```
      Dim html1 As String = WebControl1.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")
    Dim doc1 As New HtmlDocument
    doc1.LoadHtml(html1)
    WaitForPageLoad()
    Dim node As HtmlNodeCollection = doc1.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a")
    WaitForPageLoad()
    For Each links As HtmlNode In node
        If links.Attributes("href").Value = TextBox2.Text Then
            WebControl1.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("")
            Application.DoEvents()
            WaitForPageLoad()
        End If

    Next
```

i do not know where i am going wrong

Comment: *Which* error do you get in *what* line?

Comment: NullPointerException at links.Attributes("href").Value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: If you look at the value of `links` in the debugger when it goes wrong, does it have an "href" attribute?

Comment: No i am not getting the ''href'' attribute why? @Andrew Morton

Answer (score 0):

If `links.Attributes("href")` is `Nothing` then there is no `.Value` property.

You can avoid the problem with the [null-conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) `?.`:

```
If links.Attributes("href")?.Value = TextBox2.Text Then
```

Comment: One more problem is that i am not getting all the anchor tags

Comment: @AbhinandanKumar You should really ask a new question for another problem. For now, I suggest saving `html1` to a file and referring to it while examining the values of `links` in the debugger. Have a close look at what is different between what you get and what you think you should get. (Also, I see no reason for the second `WaitForPageLoad()`.)